# How can I understand numpy.sin() results?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to understand np.sin() results.
I'm trying to search on the internet to understand why

`np.sin(90)` is 0.8939966... ,

`np.sin(80)` is -0.9938886...

and `np.sin(90 * np.pi / 180)` is 1.0.

I know the purpose of π / 180 is due to converting degree to radian.

Can someone help me with the process of numpy.sin() calculations?

Comment: ```np.sin(90)``` assumes ```90``` is in radians..  which is equivalent to ```90 / np.pi * 180```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.sin`takes it's input in [radian](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sin.html). The values you wrote are correct but you must think of your input as radian not degrees. You can convert your degrees to radian with the formula you used in your [third expression](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/how-degrees-to-radians.html).